# Unable to download VIIRS images with GIBS API and gdal_translate

Tags: remote-sensing, api, gdal-translate, tile-map-service, nasa

I'm trying to download some VIIRS images from [GIBS API](https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/Map+Library+Usage#expand-GDALBasics). I'm using gdal:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 19.07 42.16 28.39 34.5 -of "GTiff" "viirs.xml" "VIIRS_SNPP_DayNightBand_ENCC.tif"
```

The viirs.xml file contains:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS"><ServerUrl>https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/VIIRS_SNPP_DayNightBand_ENCC/default/2017-08-21/500m/${z}/${y}/${x}.png</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-180.0</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>90</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>396.0</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-198</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>7</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>2</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:4326</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>512</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>512</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>4</BandsCount>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

But, it returns the following error:

```
Input file size is 131072, 655360
ERROR 1: GDALWMS: Incorrect bands count 1 in downloaded block, expected 4.
ERROR 1: GDALWMS: ReadBlockFromFile (https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/VIIRS_SNPP_DayNightBand_ENCC/default/2017-08-21/500m/7/21/88.png) failed.
ERROR 1: viirs.xml, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 88, Y offset 21
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 88, Y block offset 21
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was originated from an old gdal version (2.1.2). It works with gdal 2.2.1!

Comment: Yo, mark it answered :)